# CSS flexbox with element inside wrapper

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a problem with the ordering element. I have container (flexbox) vith one child (order=1) and sibling div (wrapper i would'nt use flexbox) with child ordered but not work.

Can see full example  : http://codepen.io/isyara/pen/HtniA   (check wrapper im-changed-order)

thanks

Comment: Your question is a little difficult to understand, do you mean that you want the second `.container` element to appear the same as the first one?  Or that the first one should be identical to the second one?

Comment: I have one child ordered and two childs into wrapper and flexbox to order the wrapper with child not in wrapper , i don't want the wrapper order just child into. (see codepen example with and without wrapper)

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to have the first example look like the second example, then you're out of luck.  Flex items can only be arranged within their flex container.

```
+---------------+
|  +---------+  |
|  |    a    |  |
|  + --------+  |
|  +---------+  |
|  |    b    |  |
|  | +-----+ |  |
|  | |  c  | |  |
|  | +-----+ |  |
|  | +-----+ |  |
|  | |  d  | |  |
|  | +-----+ |  |
|  +---------+  |
+---------------+
```

If the outer container and b are both flex containers (`display: flex` applied to them), then only these arrangements are possible:

- (c d) a
- (d c) a
- a (c d)
- a (d c)

If b is *not* a flex container, then c and d are not flex items and cannot be arranged at all using the `order` property.

Elements a, c, and d must be sibblings to fully rearrange them:

```
+---------------+
|  +---------+  |
|  |    a    |  |
|  + --------+  |
|  +---------+  |
|  |    c    |  |
|  + --------+  |
|  +---------+  |
|  |    d    |  |
|  + --------+  |
+---------------+
```

Now you can have all of the arrangements from the previous example, plus these:

- c a d
- d a c

Comment: Yes  , i would like c a d arrangements but a is not sibling of c - d.  Thanks for the explaination cimmanon